# Can't get PHP to allow memory size larger than 536870912 bytes. Magento Script

Tags: php, magento, command-line-interface, memory-limit

I am trying to run a product export with Magento's dataflow using the CLI script found here: https://www.kerstner.at/2015/07/run-magento-data-flow-profile-from-shell/

The issue I am facing is the script always stops with the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted

I have attempted to change the memory_limit for PHP in multiple places:

- Changed all php.ini files
- Added "*ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");*" to the code.
- Input "*php -d memory_limit=1024M*" at the command line.
- Checked the setting using the CLI command "*php -i | grep
  memory_limit*"
- Checked the memory_limit using *phpinfo()*

...and yet I cannot get the script to execute beyond 536870912 bytes.

Is there something built into Magneto that would stop this? I am running out of ideas.

My Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu Server 16.04
- Total/Free Memory: 8GB/6.9GB
- PHP 7.0

PHP Settings:

- /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini : memory_limit = 1024M
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini : memory_limit = 1024M

Comment: You checked on phpinfo() the param `memory_limit` to know if you do correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092271/cannot-set-unlimited-memory-limit

Comment: @ntzz I have checked on phpinfo(), it always reflects what I have in php.ini

Comment: @Gogol I tired ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'), still no luck. Always stops at 536870912 bytes. I cannot do by batch as the script runs a specific dataflow profile.

Comment: @Gogol I wish it were that simple but I have a total of 8GB ram, with only 1.1GB in use.

Comment: That is weird. WHat server are you using?

Comment: @Gogol Ubuntu Server 16.04

Comment: It probably means a configuration problem. May be your cli uses another conf file? Not really sure what's happening there. Please edit the question and add your environment details for all to understand whats going on.

Comment: Go to your `phpinfo()`, look for the location of your currently used php.ini file. Change that .ini file. Restart the service php. It would get the job done.